# Shared domain for app domain while trying to run microsoft reportviwer in legacy mode

Tags: c#, reportviewer, appdomain

I am aiming to have Microsoft report viewer on .net 4.x with .net 3.5 with NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy as noted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode?referrer=https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices)

With full trust I got

```
Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances.
```

When try with relevant permissions by [signing assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231360/492258):

```
PermissionSet permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
permissions.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None) { AllFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read });
```

it says `Local mode requires full trust.`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892955/error-while-loading-assembly-on-separated-appdomain#comment55553802_33892955) Shared domain is mentioned:

> The problem is that some assemblies (most notably, interop assemblies)
>   are not domain-specific. They use a shared domain, and thus they can
>   only be loaded once in a process. You need to make sure that all the
>   domains use the exact same assembly when that's the case. Or use full
>   trust, but that comes with its own can of worms, of course :)

For shared domain, [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles/) there is a listing like this:

> …where each of the subwebs HrWeb, EmployeeServices etc. are set up as
>   an application in the internet service manager, you will have the
>   following application domains (appdomains) in your asp.net process
>
> System Domain
>   Shared Domain
>   Default Domain
>   Root
>   HrWeb
>   EmployeeServices
>   FinanceWeb
>   SalesWeb

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1362832/492258) said:

> Any assembly can be loaded by the CLR either into the shared domain or
>   the domain that triggered the assembly load depending on the
>   configuration of the CLR instance that is loading the assembly.

<del>**My first question, what is "Shared domain", is it related to shared hosting?**</del>

[This link](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/07/25/150301.aspx) explains about "shared domain" by depicting with illustration with arguement:

> When you load an assembly into your (default) AppDomain you will load
>   it only for your current AppDomain. The types defined there are not
>   shared anywhere. There is one exception though: The types defined in
>   mscorlib are always shared between all AppDomains. The mscorlib
>   assembly is loaded into a so called Shared Domain. This is not a real
>   AppDomain but simply a placeholder domain where all assemblies are
>   loaded which can be shared between AppDomains. An assembly loaded into
>   the Shared Domain is loaded therefore AppDomain neutral. Assemblies
>   loaded AppDomain neutral have one special behavior:

[image]

So my understanding, Shared domain is on top of appdomain. But how is s it related to shared hosting? Is it w3wp.exe process has appdomains and shared domain?

On the other hand, if I play with set the `AppDomainSetup.LoaderOptimization` property, I am stuck as well because:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1362832/492258), it is said LoaderOptimization attribute *can not be* changed for iis.

However to verify I both tried with

```
        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory, LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.SingleDomain };
```

and

```
        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory, LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain };
```

but always result with:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.|[!] Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' threw an exception.
Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
```

**Second question is: I can produce report in dev machine however in test machine it fails with error message above with full trust issues. How can I reproduce the same error on my dev machine?**

**So finally How can I produce properly my report on test machine? Is it cause to use multiple application on the same domain? Do I need dedicated iis domain for this?**

Answer (score 0):

I hope I well documented my question for further readers.

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684679/492258):

```
AppDomain cad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
AppDomainSetup cads = cad.SetupInformation;
var setup = new AppDomainSetup
{
    ApplicationName = cads.ApplicationName,
    ApplicationBase = cads.ApplicationBase,
    DynamicBase = cads.DynamicBase,
    CachePath = cads.CachePath,
    PrivateBinPath = cads.PrivateBinPath,
    ShadowCopyDirectories = cads.ShadowCopyDirectories,
    ShadowCopyFiles = cads.ShadowCopyFiles,
    ApplicationTrust = cads.ApplicationTrust,
    LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.SingleDomain
};
setup.SetCompatibilitySwitches(new[] { "NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy" });
AppDomain _casPolicyEnabledDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Dummy", cad.Evidence,setup
);
```

Until that answer what I was missing `which would inherit all setup properties from the current one but LoaderOptimization`. That means I was only doing:

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory, LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.SingleDomain }; 
AppDomain _casPolicyEnabledDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Full Trust", null, setup);
```